# An editable text field in an UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

On your iPhone (iOS 5), go to Settings -> General -> Network -> Cellular Data Network. How can I get similar looking cells with editable text fields? Or do I have to create it on my own?

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a screenshot for these of us who have multiple iOS devices, but prefer talking into a handset rather than an iPod :)

Comment: You do have to do some work. [Here is a similar question to yours with some potentially useful answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568214/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive your own class from UITableViewCell, and return that from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
In your own UITableViewCell, you can do pretty much what you like.

Answer (score 0):

Place UIImageVIew (use the image you want to display on the right side) and dump editable text fields on that UIImageVIew on the left.