# How to get UITextField value on custom UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, uitextfield

I'm new to IOS development and i'm trying to develop my first app.

So my problem is... I've got a UITableView with custom cells, each cell contains an UITextField. When I press a button I'd like to put each UITextField value in a NSMutableArray.

I think I've got to do something like that but I'm not sure:

```
NSMutableArray *playerNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < nbPlayers; i++){ //nbPlayers is the number of rows in the UITableView
    NSString *playerName =UITextField.text;
    [playerNameArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", playerName]];
}
```

If someone can help me.... :)
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You need to reference the instance of your `UITextField`, what you're doing there is attempting to call `text` on the `UITextField` class. Something like this would probably solve your problem:

```
NSMutableArray *playerNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < nbPlayers; i++){ //nbPlayers is the number of rows in the UITableView

    MyTableViewCellSubclass *theCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    UITextField *cellTextField = [theCell textField];

    NSString *playerName = [cellTextField text];
    [playerNameArray addObject:playerName];
}
```

Comment: This works as long as you have declared that UITextField as a property named textField in your custom TableViewCell subclass.

Answer (score 5):

The text field passed to your delegate is a subview of the cell's contentView.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview;
      NSIndexPath *txtIndPath = [self.tblPendingDeliveryData indexPathForCell:cell];
    
      write you code here.....like
      if(textField.tag == 1)
      {
          NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self.arrPendingDeliveryData objectAtIndex:txtIndPath.row];
          [dict setObject:textField.text forKey:@"ReOrder"];
      }

}
```

In txtIndPath you will get active textfield's indexpath. Assign the textfield tag property with necessary value. It works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this thread for a similar question

[UITextField in UITableViewCell Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568214/uitextfield-in-uitableviewcell-help)

You should to use one of the textfield delegated method to fill the proper cell of your array

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   }
```